# Unity Move rotating object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball which rotates around the point 0,0,0 in the Z-axis. When the space button is pressed, the ball has to go inside the large circle. Now my code looks like this. When you press space, the ball does not behave as they should. I want to know how to make a balloon down exactly down

that's how the ball should behave ->
[behavior image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ade36.png)

my code:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y - 1, 0);
    } else {
        transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0,0,1), 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to 'jump' the orbit doesn't do what you want because [Transform.RotateAround](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) modifies both the rotation and the position of the object's transform. [image: Demonstration of how RotateAround modifies the transform]

So jumping to (position - 1,1,0) in the world is going to return wildly different results every time.

What you want to do instead is calculate the (Vector) direction from the object to the centre of orbit (the **difference**), then **scale** that down to how far you want it to move, then **apply** it to the position.

```
private Vector3 _orbitPos = Vector3.zero;
private float _orbitAngle = 2f;

private float _distanceToJump = 2f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        var difference = (_orbitPos - transform.position).normalized * _distanceToJump;
        transform.Translate(difference);
    }

    transform.RotateAround(_orbitPos, Vector3.forward, _orbitAngle);
}
```

This will move the object to be orbiting 2 units closer when space is pressed immediately.

*If you wanted to have a smooth transition instead of a jump, look into using [Mathf.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html), Vector3.Lerp and the routines involved.*

Comment: thank you for this informative answer. but it doesn't work. I used transform.translate without any other calculations and it worked. I just didn't know about this method, as I am a beginner in unity3d

Comment: So what values did you give to transform.Translate() then? And this method is minor mathematics, not unique to Unity!

Comment: "But it doesn't work." But I assure you it does. Either you've made a mistake when transcribing it, or your question doesn't fully explain what you wanted.